# chart.js scale xaxis with date, strange renderer

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hi i got this renderer with my config on chart.js, i dont understand why i got

[image]

this is the version of chart.js

```html
/*!
 * Chart.js
 * http://chartjs.org/
 * Version: 2.7.1
 *
 * Copyright 2017 Nick Downie
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 */
```

i generate my chart with this function and i dont understand how to fix my problem
thanks for your help

```html
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: datadate,
            datasets: [{ 
                data: datavalue,
                label: "Value array",
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                pointRadius: 3,
                pointHoverRadius: 3,
                fill: false
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
                title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'returned value'
                },
                
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: false
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [ {
                        type: 'time',
                       time: {
                        min: Math.min.apply(null, datadate),
                        max: Math.max.apply(null, datadate)
                       }
                    }],
                },
                responsive: true
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Chart.js version to `3.0.0` or above instead of `2.7.1`, works well in updated versions.

see the example below which is made on Chart.js  version `3.0.0`.

**Note**: below is a simple line chart example.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("tests-chart");
const data =[
  { x: "24/03/2022", y: 20 },
  { x: "25/03/2022", y: 5 },
  { x: "24/06/2022", y: 10 },
  { x: "25/06/2022", y: 5 }
 ];

const testsChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("tests-chart"), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{ 
                data: data,
                label: "Value array",
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                pointRadius: 3,
                pointHoverRadius: 3,
                fill: false
                }
            ]
        },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="tests-chart"></canvas>
</div>
```